# How do I implement Lottie for Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, lottie

I went through the documentation of how to implement Lottie animation library.

I added the NuGet package Lottie for Xamarin.Forms 1.0.0.7 and while debugging my android project for Xamarin Forms, it builds without an error but doesn't display an animation of the json file in my project.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code so we can try to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lottie step by step in Xamarin forms:

1. Install the Lottie Package in all your projects
2. Init Lottie in both projects Android and iOS, using  AnimationViewRenderer.Init();
3. Add your view in your XAML or using CodeBehind, in the case of XAML you have to add the reference xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
4. Add your JSON to your project:

In iOS add it into your project and make sure you have the build action in Bundle Resource

In Android, put it in you Assets folder and make sure you have the build action in Android Asset

You can find a sample here:

https://xamgirl.com/lottie-animations-step-by-step-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I have followed the steps but the animation doesn't comeup on iOS , whereas it works fine on Android

Comment: I have the same problem, works fine on android just not loading on iOS (_no errors or crashes_). Did you find a solution? @AshishKumar

Comment: @leuanW Please downgrade the nuget , the latest one is buggy.I am using Com.Airbnb.iOS.Lottie" version="2.1.3.0",Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie" version="2.3.4

Comment: Same problem here, I folowed all steps and still don't get any result. On android project I get a square but not the animation, and on IOS nothing.

Answer (score 3):

seems that AnimationViewRenderer doesn't exist the the current context when trying to add it to MainActivity.cs